# How to pass dynamic value to div element and then access it - React ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I'm mapping all of my files

```
  _renderItems = files =>
    files
      ? files.map((item, i) => {
          return <ProjectItemUser {...item} key={i} index={i} />;
        })
      : null;
```

and then I'm trying to display it `ProjectItemUser`

```
class ProjectItemUser extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="book_item">
          <div className="book_header">
            <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="book_this">
            <div className="book_author">{this.props.subject}</div>

            <div className="book_bubble">
              <strong>Study: </strong> {this.props.study}
            </div>

            <div className="book_bubble">
              <strong>Grade: </strong> {this.props.grade}
            </div>

            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="trash" id="trash" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This basically displays all the files, and each file is its own separate row. I would like to assign value to div element on each iteration, so I can control which file has been clicked.

I can access my id with: `this.props._id`

Should this be done using refs and if so, how ?

Comment: btw you should use better key than `i`. `item.id`, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `onClick` function as parameter

```
 _renderItems = files =>
    files
      ? files.map((item, i) => {
          return <ProjectItemUser {...item} key={i} index={i} onClick={() => { console.warn(item) } />;
        })
      : null;


class ProjectItemUser extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="book_item">
          <div className="book_header">
            <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
          </div>
          <div className="book_this">
            <div className="book_author">{this.props.subject}</div>

            <div className="book_bubble">
              <strong>Study: </strong> {this.props.study}
            </div>

            <div className="book_bubble">
              <strong>Grade: </strong> {this.props.grade}
            </div>

            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="trash" id="trash" />

            <Button onClick={this.props.onClick} label="Click on me" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: From my understanding,  this just display all the id's on each iteration ? I want to stick it to the element, so each row has it's own. In case your solution works, how would you get the id of the particular element that you clicked ?

Comment: See `console.warn`, `item` will be equal to clicked item

Comment: Of course, you should implemented `onClick` event inside `ProjectItemUser`

Comment: That's the point, it's not. Because it calls itself on every iteration, so instead I get all id's displayed at once, but when I click element nothing happens.

Comment: I added explanation for `ProjectItemUser`